# How to apply Custom Styling XF.Material controls

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, material-design

I am using XF.Material library for my Xamarin Forms project, as per the [instructions](https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library#material-resources) I have created Material Resources in App.xaml and passed configuration name as a parameter to the initializer. bur for some reason I do not see any application-specific style (Colors and Fonts) instead it is using Material style (Purple color).

I have also tried creating MaterialConfiguration instance in the code-behind and assigned it to the initializer but still, it is not taking any custom style.

Yes, I have added the plist entry as per the instructions.....

What am I missing any idea???

[image]

[image]

[image]

UPDATE:

I have tried adding dynamic configuration like below but snackbar did not take it!!

[image]

Comment: Have you followed all steps in the [getting-started](https://github.com/Baseflow/XF-Material-Library#getting-started)? Call the init method in both xamarin.forms project and Xamarin.iOS project.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT Yes I followed the getting started instructions and Yes I called Init() in Android and IOS projects